# Having problem on how to give condition if the Data = N/A then it will get disappear?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm having a problem on **how to make the reason get disappear** if API data for reason is **N/A**. Currently I'm using the below code and it is not working. Please do help me out.

```
{invoiceInfo.reason !== N/A ? (
   <Text style={[GlobalStyle.ReceiptDeclinedReason]}>Reason: {invoiceInfo.reason}</Text>
 ) : N/A}
```

API Data:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change to:

```html
{invoiceInfo.reason !== "N/A" ? (
   <Text style={[GlobalStyle.ReceiptDeclinedReason]}>Reason: {invoiceInfo.reason}</Text>
 ) : <></>}
```

Comment: but stil i can see word "N/A" appearing.

Comment: @vesh updated the code, try that now for the word to disappear